# Laravel 5.1 API Enable Cors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cors

I've looked for some ways to enable cors on Laravel 5.1 specifically, and I have found some libs like:

https://github.com/neomerx/cors-illuminate

https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

but none of them has an implementation tutorial specifically for Laravel 5.1,  I tried to config but It doesn't work.

If someone already implemented CORS on Laravel 5.1 I would be grateful for the help...

Comment: Barryvdh's is for Laravel 5, and really it should work out of the box with 5.1 as well. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I tried, but I still getting the following message ( it's a angular frontend)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.address.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

But I have already added the local address on the cors files

'supportsCredentials' => true,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['http://127.0.0.1:8080'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
    'hosts' => [],

Comment: Which message do you get?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load api.address.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '127.0.0.1:8080'; is therefore not allowed access

Comment: Did you publish the config file and edit it accordingly?

Comment: Did you have a look at the response header in your browser? There the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header should be set to the right domain. Also you could try to set it yourself on one route "by hand"...

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Credentials → true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *

The cors seems to woking, I already tried my localhost instead of * but still don't working

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Here is my CORS middleware:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CORS {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
        ];
        if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
            return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach($headers as $key => $value)
            $response->header($key, $value);
        return $response;
    }

}
```

To use CORS middleware you have to register it first in your app\Http\Kernel.php file like this:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        //other middlewares
        'cors' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CORS',
    ];
```

Then you can use it in your routes

```
Route::get('example', array('middleware' => 'cors', 'uses' => 'ExampleController@dummy'));
```

###### Edit: In Laravel ^8.0 you have to import the namespace of the controller and use the class like this:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\ExampleController;

Route::get('example', [ExampleController::class, 'dummy'])->middleware('cors');
```

Comment: Works on Apache but not IIS :(

Comment: Just to clarify - is this an alternative to the packages mentioned in the question?

Comment: @retrograde yeah if you pick this solution you don't have to use a package.

Comment: This is really good solutions, also the OPTIONS method to check if Origin is allowed - like it in the middleware - But for some reason I can not get it all running for POST methods in laravel 5.X - Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add a method spoof somewhere? When I call POST/GET I get to this middleware but using method OPTIONS I do not get to this middleware on the same route? Really odd... in the route list there is no OPTIONS method so I'm presuming it's possibly that the method OPTIONS is invalid OR being caught elsewhere. This is laravel 5.4 so could be something that's been added?

Comment: Note that, for me it is version 5.6 , and I also needed to add `\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class` at Kernel.php, inside `protected $middleware` array. If anyone has suffer like me, can try this

Comment: @AlexKyriakidis Thanks for the solution, as I am using the laravel5.7 and I have this syntax `return $next($request);` in my middleware. Should I use this or not?

Comment: This will enable access for the whole site / program, not just APIs.

Comment: This is failing on OPTIONS.

Comment: @arikanmstf you just made my week!! This was the problem I was having with my CORS. You are right, adding it to the protected $middleware in kernel.php fixed it! Many thanks.

Comment: Just add App\Http\Middleware\CORS::class in protected $middleware, and it will work for any request

Comment: THANK YOU! Jeez I've struggled with this for weeks. None of the packages worked for me. This is great!

Comment: This didn't not work for me in Laravel 6.9, this did: https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: This is a nice and simple solution, much thanks. But I changed route on my web.php to get it working on Laravel 5.5 `Route::get('example', 'ExampleController@dummy')->middleware(CORS::class);`

Comment: Worked like a charm for L5.2 for me.. just a quick note, CORS handling is inbuilt with L8 now.. Thanks

Comment: This solution is generally too complex for those that want their local development environment to just work without the pain of CORS.

Answer (score 50):

I always use an easy method. Just add below lines to `\public\index.php` file. You don't have to use a middleware I think.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Comment: it is not elegant

Comment: @EfriandikaPratama why not? `index.php` file is being used on all HTTP requests. So it is an easy and user-friendly way.

Comment: It is not elegant. More elegant if you put that code in middleware.

Comment: @EfriandikaPratama saying the same thing over and over doesn't prove your point.

Comment: it is good if you want to enable CORS for your complete app, but not applicable if you want to enable CORS on certain routes. which I think make more sense to use Middleware instead.

Comment: This is short and sweet, I think protecting in middleware isn't necessary when all routes are already protected with OAuth or JWT.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am tired of installing bunch of packages just to implement a simple feature

Comment: This solution is incomplete. It solved partially the CORS error, it didn't work on some POST requests.

Comment: This is a great solution. It's unfortunate that Laravel doesn't have an inbuilt quick way to turn this off.

Answer (score 14):

I am using Laravel 5.4 and unfortunately although the accepted answer seems fine, for preflighted requests (like `PUT` and `DELETE`) which will be preceded by an `OPTIONS` request, specifying the middleware in the `$routeMiddleware` array (and using that in the routes definition file) will not work unless you define a route handler for `OPTIONS` as well. This is because without an `OPTIONS` route Laravel will [internally respond](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L170-L177) to that method without the CORS headers.

So in short either define the middleware in the `$middleware` array which runs globally for all requests or if you're doing it in `$middlewareGroups` or `$routeMiddleware` then also define a route handler for `OPTIONS`. This can be done like this:

```
Route::match(['options', 'put'], '/route', function () {
    // This will work with the middleware shown in the accepted answer
})->middleware('cors');
```

I also wrote a middleware for the same purpose which looks similar but is larger in size as it tries to be more configurable and handles a bunch of conditions as well:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{
    private static $allowedOriginsWhitelist = [
      'http://localhost:8000'
    ];

    // All the headers must be a string

    private static $allowedOrigin = '*';

    private static $allowedMethods = 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE';

    private static $allowCredentials = 'true';

    private static $allowedHeaders = '';

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      if (! $this->isCorsRequest($request))
      {
        return $next($request);
      }

      static::$allowedOrigin = $this->resolveAllowedOrigin($request);

      static::$allowedHeaders = $this->resolveAllowedHeaders($request);

      $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'       => static::$allowedOrigin,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'      => static::$allowedMethods,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'      => static::$allowedHeaders,
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'  => static::$allowCredentials,
      ];

      // For preflighted requests
      if ($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS')
      {
        return response('', 200)->withHeaders($headers);
      }

      $response = $next($request)->withHeaders($headers);

      return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Incoming request is a CORS request if the Origin
     * header is set and Origin !== Host
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     */
    private function isCorsRequest($request)
    {
      $requestHasOrigin = $request->headers->has('Origin');

      if ($requestHasOrigin)
      {
        $origin = $request->headers->get('Origin');

        $host = $request->getSchemeAndHttpHost();

        if ($origin !== $host)
        {
          return true;
        }
      }

      return false;
    }

    /**
     * Dynamic resolution of allowed origin since we can't
     * pass multiple domains to the header. The appropriate
     * domain is set in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header
     * only if it is present in the whitelist.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     */
    private function resolveAllowedOrigin($request)
    {
      $allowedOrigin = static::$allowedOrigin;

      // If origin is in our $allowedOriginsWhitelist
      // then we send that in Access-Control-Allow-Origin

      $origin = $request->headers->get('Origin');

      if (in_array($origin, static::$allowedOriginsWhitelist))
      {
        $allowedOrigin = $origin;
      }

      return $allowedOrigin;
    }

    /**
     * Take the incoming client request headers
     * and return. Will be used to pass in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     */
    private function resolveAllowedHeaders($request)
    {
      $allowedHeaders = $request->headers->get('Access-Control-Request-Headers');

      return $allowedHeaders;
    }
}
```

Also written a [blog post](http://codecipher.in/laravel-cors/) on this.

Comment: Awesome, I read your blog post and it worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: @Rishabh I Was just checking about some CORS related Laravel issues, almost every answer is just the same, but this one is actually very nice ..

Answer (score 12):

For me i put this codes in `public\index.php` file. and it worked just fine for all CRUD operations.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, post, get');
header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

Answer (score 10):

[barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) works perfectly with Laravel 5.1 with just a few key points in enabling it.

1. After adding it as a composer dependency, make sure you have published the CORS config file and adjusted the CORS headers as you want them. Here is how mine look in **app/config/cors.php**

   ```
   <?php

   return [

       'supportsCredentials' => true,
       'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
       'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
       'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE'],
       'exposedHeaders' => ['DAV', 'content-length', 'Allow'],
       'maxAge' => 86400,
       'hosts' => [],
   ];
   ```
2. After this, there is one more step that's not mentioned in the documentation, you have to add the CORS handler `'Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors'` in the App kernel. I prefer to use it in the global middleware stack. Like this

   ```
   /**
    * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
    *
    * @var array
    */
   protected $middleware = [
       'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
       'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
       'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
       'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
       'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',

       'Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors',

   ];
   ```

   But its up to you to use it as a route middleware and place on specific routes.

This should make the package work with L5.1

Comment: I have been looking for details on each of the config file's elements especially 'exposedHeaders' and 'supportsCredentials', but unfortunately haven't had any success yet, do you mind to give some details on them or maybe post a reference please? much appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't return a response from your route either through function closure or through controller action then it won't work.

## It's not working

**Controller Action**

```
Route::post('login','AuthController@login');

class AuthController extends Controller {

     ...

     public function login() {
          dd(['key' => 'value']);
          //OR
          die(['key' => 'value']);
          //OR
          print_r(['key' => 'value');
          exit();
     }

     ...

}
```

## It works!

**Controller Action**

```
Route::post('login','AuthController@login');

class AuthController extends Controller {

     ...

     public function login() {
          return response()->json(['key' => 'value'], 200);
          // OR
          return ['key' => 'value'];
          // OR
          $data = ['key' => 'value'];
          return $data;
     }

     ...

}
```

### Test CORS

Chrome -> Developer Tools -> Network tab

[image]

If anything goes wrong then your response headers won't be here.

Answer (score 2):

**Laravel 8**

Create a middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', config('cors.allowed_origins')) 
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', config('cors.allowed_methods'))
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',config('cors.allowed_headers'));
    }
}
```

**config/cors.php**

```
return [
    'paths' => [
        'api/*', 
        'admin/api/*', 
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
    ],
    'allowed_methods' => [ //'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS'
        'GET', 
        'POST', 
        'PUT', 
        'PATCH', 
        'DELETE', 
        'OPTIONS'
    ],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => [//  'Content-Type, Authorization, Accept'
        'Content-Type', 
        'Authorization', 
        'Accept'
    ],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => true,
];
```

**kernel.php** for http

```
    protected $middleware = [
        ... ,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class,  // Cors middlewate
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Use this library. Follow the instruction mention in this repo.

Remember don't use `dd()` or `die()` in the CORS URL because this library will not work. Always use return with the CORS URL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just use this as a middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

and register the middleware in your kernel file on this path `app/Http/Kernel.php` in which group that you prefer and everything will be fine