# React native call API axios network

Tags: react-native

I am trying to get the API on the react-native interface by calling with Axios but getting a network error. My API is written in .net core version 3.0.
I have successfully tried postman but failed to call
Please help me fix it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bN1c.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVjwY.png)

Comment: CORS issue may be?

Comment: please doublecheck the IP 10:20:*:* vs localhost under the same network.

Answer (score 0):

You can passing header in your axios request to fix CORS as Ketan Rampteke's reply.
[Follow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42474262/cors-issue-with-external-api-works-via-postman-but-not-http-request-with-axios) .

Chào thân ái người anh em <3