# Sending data from javascript to Laravel Controller

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I've got a problem with sending data from javascript to my controller.
There is my **Ajax**:

```
var point = JSON.stringify(points);

function onBtnClick() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
      header:{
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN':$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });

    $.post('http://localhost/updateC', {
        data: point,
        dataType: 'json', 
        contentType:'application/json', 
    })
    .done(function() {
        alert('success');
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });

}
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::resource('/races','RacesController');
Route::post('updateC', 'RacesController@Points');
```

And there is my **RacesController:**

```
public function Points(Request $request) {
    $test = $request->input('data');
    return "$test";
}
```

And the error is saying that has been blocked by CORS-polices.

Comment: You need to add the x-csrf-token header, check out the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf

Comment: What is the data you have to post?... or show your form?

Comment: data are my  points that i've created points[currentid] = {id: currentid, x: event.offsetX, y: event.offsetY};
  currentid++;

Comment: have you added `<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">` in your ajax sending page. and please screenshot of your Browser console. Ajax request.

Comment: I've tried in and still doesn't work.But here is my error [link](https://imgur.com/a/JRIwRae)

Comment: @Patrik `Route::post('updateC', ['uses' =>'RacesController@Points', 'as' => 'race.post']); $.post("{{route('race.post')}}", {` Change the above code and try. If your access domain and ajax url domain is not same then url is also blocked. Your access url is 127.0.0.1 and ajax url is localhost. (ref your screenshot)

Comment: Well i've done same searching by my self and the main error is now solved.I've tried your solution now and there is this other error [link](https://imgur.com/a/kd88h5N).And there is my new ajax ` $.ajax( {
        url:"{{route('race.post')}}",
        type:'POST',
        data:{
          _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
          _method:'PUT',
          points:point,
          dataType: 'json', 
          contentType:'application/json', 
        }
        
        
    })`

Comment: why you use `_method:'PUT'` this should be POST in route POST. screenshot of ajax respone from network tab it will help to understand the error.

Comment: Someone told me when updating someting you should use method PUT so i tried it. There is the response [link](https://imgur.com/a/9bUFiOR).

Comment: Ok if you use PUT method then in route also need to define as Route::PUT. change it and give it a try. also check the log file about the error. and the response image u uploaded is only the data u sent to server. but i need the response from the server. where error exeption is thrown.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin

check this

Comment: I've done some changes and the error disappear but another show up.. and it is this one [link](https://imgur.com/a/PFcDlsL).

Comment: send screenshot eg. [https://imgur.com/DxBOpnF](https://imgur.com/DxBOpnF)

Comment: Welll the are the screenshots and it looks interesting. [preview](https://imgur.com/a/LZQi0LN) and [response](https://imgur.com/a/iyNVpfd)

Comment: its is because of csrf_token() if u used {{csrf_token()}} in .js file it will not compiled not going to work. **<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}** try **_token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')**

Answer (score 0):

go the middleware folder, the verifycsrftoken file,

```
app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

and add this url to the except array

```
protected $except = [
   ....
   http://localhost/updateC
];
```

to handle exceptions to your ajax post requests, then you can then use the

[Barryvdh Laravel Cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) package to get rid of cors issue,

if you are using laravel 5.6, you dont need any CORs package for that,

just create a CORs Middleware

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
class Cors {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $allowedOrigins = ['http://oursite.com', '*.myost.net','*','www.aminu.*'];
        $origin = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] : '';
        if (in_array($origin, $allowedOrigins)) {
            return $next($request)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin)
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers',' Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With, cache-control,postman-token, token')
                ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials',' true');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

and add middleware to the kernel.php file

```
protected $middleware = [
    ......
    \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class, //added here
];
```

Comment: You may want to specify in your route the used middleware: `Route::post('/updateC', array('middleware' => 'cors', 'uses' => 'RaceController@point'));`, after registering this middleware in your `app\Http\Kernel.php` file.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors

Comment: I've registered it and used your Route and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add **csrf token** in your `data` property of ajax post like this:

```
data: {
    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    "point": point
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed still the same error.Look at the 1st answer i've linked it.

Answer (score 0):

```php
app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

and add this route to the except array

```php
protected $except = [
   'updateC'
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ajax code

```
var abc = 'hello world';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://your url',
    data : { abc : abc }
    success: function (data) {

        // write your code
    },
    error: function (data) {
        // write your code
    }
});
```