# Laravel PUT routes return 404

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to update data in the database 
but it returns error 404 not found in postman

```
Route::put('/products/{id}','productController@update');
```

Comment: Have you set the necessary cors headers

Comment: yes i did @AdityaThakur

Comment: can i see your middleware?

Comment: do you mean the middleware in the kernal file? @AdityaThakur

Comment: no i mean where you've set the cors headers,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors

Comment: 'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
 I guess this is it !? @AdityaThakur

Comment: if you've set it as your route middleware then you'll need to add it to your `Route::put('/products/{id}','productController@update')->middlerware('your middleware alias from kernel.php');`

Comment: is there any reference that I can understand it more clearly @AdityaThakur

Comment: you can try this https://laravel-nepal.com/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-laravel-5/

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'Accept: application/json' header to request.

Answer (score -1):

Please provide more code so we can find exactly where your problem is.

I assume you wrote the route in the `api.php` file and not in `web.php` file.

If you do so, you must enter the route as `api/products/1`.

You have to be aware of the route group prefix as well if you are using it. Every routes inside a group prefix will be wrapped and requires the prefix string in the beginning every time you want to access it.

For instance:

in `web.php` file:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::put('products/{id}', 'productController@update');
});

# this will require you to access the url by tyiping "api/products/1".
```

and in the `api php` file (this is the more likely for new users have to be aware):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::put('products/{id}', 'productController@update');
});

# this will require you to access the url by tyiping "api/api/products/1" since the api.php file will automatically wrap your routes within an api prefix.
```

and one more thing you need to know, if you are using a `getRoutesKeyName` method on your model, you should follow wether the wildcard to use id's or maybe slug based on what you type inside the method.

For instance:

```
public function getRoutesKeyName(){
    return 'slug';
}
# this will require you to type "products/name-of-product" instead of "products/1"
```

Comment: no need to add `['prefix' => 'api']`, if the route is listed api.php, `/api` is automatically added to these routes,

Comment: @AdityaThakur that is just an example to get 404 error on your api routes. I don't say that you need to add prefix, just be aware of using it. please read carefully.