# Getting 401 unauthorized in Laravel passport, vueJS and Axios

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, http-headers, axios

I am a bit new to VueJS and I want to get data from an Laravel *(passport)* API, so for that I used `npm i axios` for API requests and this is my script code from **App.vue** file:

```
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  created() {
    const postData = {
      grant_type: "password",
      client_id: 2,
      client_secret: 'MvEyvm3MMr0VJ5BlrJyzoKzsjmrVpAXp9FxJHsau',
      username: 'my-email@gmail.com',
      password: '********',
      scope: ''
    }
    axios.post('http://localhost/api/oauth/token', postData)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data.access_token);
      const header = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + response.data.access_token,
      };
      axios.get('http://localhost/api/api/user', {headers: header})
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

The **API.PHP** *(routes file for API)*:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});
```

And this is the Middleware code for **CORS** fixing in Laravel:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $domains = ["http://localhost:8080"];

    if (isset($request->server()['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        $origin = $request->server()['HTTP_ORIGIN'];
        if (in_array($origin, $domains)) {
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $origin);
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Authorization');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Look at the `console.log(response.data.access_token)`, I am getting the token logged in the console but the next request gives me **401 unauthorized** error, I tried many solutions but not worked, any suggestions?

Comment: `http://localhost/api/api/user` should be `http://localhost/api/user` Not?

Comment: no `http://localhost/api` that's my project-name and the next `api` is for accessing the **API Routes**.

Comment: Please share the route configuration.

Comment: Check now I have updated!

Comment: Please ensure you hav followed all these steps.. https://medium.com/modulr/create-api-authentication-with-passport-of-laravel-5-6-1dc2d400a7f

Comment: Also try add `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` in header

Comment: Getting this now `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/api/api/user' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy`;

Comment: for the time being please remove the domain validation from the cors settings..

Comment: Would be greate if you can use the `cors` package or follow this ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors

Comment: Please anyone help meee!

Answer (score 0):

you need to send the token with axios request in the header so the backend knows its legit, you can only do that after you check your backend is working fine with postman, now you can set the axios header like this `axios.defaults.baseURL = '/api';
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Bearer " +
        your_token_variable`