# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'abc.com' from origin 'xyz.com' has been blocked by CORS policy No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

i have tried cors middleware and similiar laravel packages its , but cant access outside url , some body can give good solution

kernel.php

```
\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
```

Cors Middlware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)


{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    //ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization',
    ];
    if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS"){
        //The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return response()->json('OK',200,$headers);
    }
    $response = $next($request);
    foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
        $response->header($key, $value);
    }
    return $response;

}
```

Comment: How and where are you implementing this middleware?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.1 API Enable Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors)

Comment: the url you shared i followed , in the last hes saying route , but why should i make route however i am accessing url which is api url , why i need route then

Comment: Are both domains under your control? Which one did you put the CORS headers on?

Comment: yes both domains are my under control , domain is same but playing on subdomains like a.mydomain.com to b.mydomain.com i have installed cors on a.mydomain because i am hitting b.mydomain

Comment: If you're hitting `b.mydomain` from `a.mydomain`, you need the CORS headers on `b.mydomain`, not `a.mydomain`.

Comment: i have tried its not working , add headers to method and controller same error happpens