# Ajax post block CORS

Tags: ajax, laravel, api

i will try to a bulk data send to another domain via api that will created at controller in laravel project

my function

```
 public function test_prod_insert()
    {
       $usrl= url('/public/wheel_images/rohana_imgs');
        $users = DB::table('products')->select('id','title','sku','image1')->skip(0)->take(2)->get();
        echo"<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='https://trk.mtrl.me/tracking.js?token=**********'></script>";

        foreach($users as $data){
    echo"<script>
        var model = {
  'time': 1518004715732,
  'token': '***************',
  'platform': 'laravel',
  'pluginVersion': '1.1.0',
  'params': {
    'categories': [
      '2'
    ],
    'id': '<?= $data->id ?>',
    'sku': '<?= $data->sku ?>',
    'imageUrl': '<?= $usrl ?>/<?= $data->image1 ?>',
    'name': '<?= $data->title ?>',
    'price': '',
    'url': '',
    'options': [

    ]
  }
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    url: 'https://trk.mtrl.me/product',
    contentType: 'application/json'
}).done(function(res) {       
    console.log('res', res);
    // Do something with the result :)
});
</script>";
}
    }
```

in console show " mysite has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response " i try some similar answer but the issue is not solved please help me to solve this issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that you can do much in CORS: But it's all realted to the host site that you are calling, Basically it's a browser feature so it will prevent the request to host site if in the headers it doesn't see

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"
```

So in your host site which you are calling, just make sure that it accept connections from your domain and then you can call the API.

**EDIT**
Writing this again don't make sense, But this is how you can implement it

[Add CORS as Middleware in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors/33090515#33090515)

Comment: "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"  how i apply this in script

Comment: because postman makes curl request in the back. but XHR request are browser based. what's your backend programming language

Comment: laravel is used

Comment: I am editing my answer you can read, how you can control this

Comment: ya i follow the same steps but show  Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://trk.mtrl.me/product. (Reason: missing token ‘content-type’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).

Comment: This is a bad practice but put this line in public/index.php file  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); and then try again

Comment: i will try in admin side