# Laravel Option Request Getting Cors Error In Firefox Only

Tags: angular, laravel, cors, laravel-6

This is a wired problem i am facing.. I research a lot but could not find any solution . So that i am posting it here..
This problem is only Happening In Firefox.. Not in any other browser(chrome,e, i have checked).. The Option Request throws the `cors` error sometimes though its succeeding sometimes

The Console Error

```
[Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://bla-bla. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)]
```

My laravel Cors handeler

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    { 
        ///// New Try ////////////

        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Key ,Authorization'
        ];
        if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            return response()->json('OK', 200, $headers);
        }
        $response = $next($request);
        foreach($headers as $key => $value){
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

Kernel.php:

```
protected $middleware = [
        .....
        \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
protected $routeMiddleware = [
         .....
        'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
    ];
```

api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'] , function() {
    Route::post('admin-login','CustomLogin@userLogin');
    Route::post('admin/login','CustomLogin@betUserLogin');
    Route::get('logout/{type}','CustomLogin@logOut')->middleware('auth:api');
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin/','middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
        Route::post('list-user','Admin\AdminController@userList');
    )};
    Route::group(['prefix' => '','middleware' => 'auth:bet_api'], function() {
        Route::post('list-user','Admin\AdminController@userList');
    )};
)};
```

[image]

> Edit 1:
>   I found that its something else (i dont have much idea)
>   that its getting error on Remote address Like 443 port where it should be in 80 for the HTTP req
>   Remote Address:[2606:4700:8d9d:0:a06f:2cb7:681f:405d]:443  ,
>   But for the first time when i am loging It going To 80 for some apis

Here is the Success OPTION request

[image]

Can Anyone Help me out! 
1.Is it a server related issue?
2. After providing the Custom Response header anything else to do?

Comment: Are you using any Cloud VM instance like EC2 ? In my experience it happened with me when i used multiple vm and cor was not configured in all the instances

Comment: You don't need to forward (next()) the request if it's OPTIONS method. Follow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33090515/6120338

Comment: Check the Edit please