# Data Transfer Error Angular CLI to Laravel (Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header)

Tags: angular, laravel, http-headers, http-post, angular-cli

I have sent data Angular side to laravel side if I use get method it's running without errors, but if I pick the post method, I get an error

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Does anyone know about this? And this is should be header encrypt error

```
// Angular Code

import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';
import {RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {BaseurlService} from '../BaseUrl/baseurl.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CompanyControlService {

  headers: Headers = new Headers();
  Options: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private configurl: BaseurlService) {

    this.headers.append('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');
    this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.headers.append('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');

    // @ts-ignore
    this.Options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});

  }

  addEmployer(newRecode) {
    return this.http.post<any>(this.configurl.configUrlLoard() + 'employer/add', newRecode);
  }

}

// Laravel Code

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EmployerController extends Controller
{
    function addEmployer()
    {
        error_log('Incoming request');
//        errorlog(request('companyNo'));
    }
}

//laravel route

Route::post('employer/add','EmployerController@addEmployer');
```

Comment: Hi! Can you post the exact error you're getting after your code?

Answer (score 0):

two solutions for ur problem:
1 first solution (the most easy solution ) u should enable cors from the backend side u can  read it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors)

2nd solution in ur front end side ,try to use proxy config in ur angular app by adding proxy.config.json under ur src app the full solution is [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d)

dont forget to rserve ur angular app with npm run start