# angular: post-request to Laravel-API not working while it's working in Postman

Tags: angular, laravel, post, postman

I can't get my Angular App working to send a http request to my locally running laravel-api.
In Postman it's working perfectly, but I can't get it working in Angular.

This is the working post-request triggered by Postman. [image: Postman POST-Request - works]

This is my Angular-logic:

```
login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
    let body = new FormData();
    body.append('email', username);
    body.append('password', password);
    this.http.post(this.LOGIN_USER_URL, body);

    return this.http.post<any>(this.LOGIN_USER_URL, body);
  }
```

If I run my angular application and the post-requests get triggered, it's returning nothing:
[image]

Does anybody know, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Your angular code snippet has the post request being made twice it seems. Also  you need to set X-CSRF token for any form/post request with a csrf token - don't know how it's done in angular setup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that CORS wasn't enabled in my laravel-api. This is the solution, that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34895806/8349707

I solved it by adding the following lines to my index.php file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
```

Comment: I think this is a 'hacky' solution, consider another approach to enable CORS in your api

Comment: @OwenKelvin Thank you for commenting. I will look for another approach before I publish my project.