# CORS error, unable to solve, Why always getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: laravel, nginx, axios, cors

I am using axios with react. and trying to send an API call to another domain (ngnix, laravel). I have did all the things to solve the CORS error, still I am getting this :

```
(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ does not match ‘*, https://www.assamhut.com, *’).
```

Axios Code:

```
const API_ROUTE = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        "Key": token,
        "Id": user_id
    }
});

export async function login_user(email, password) {
    await csrf_token();
    var result = await API_ROUTE.post('/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
    });
    return result.data;
}
```

Laravel CORS middleware:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure                 $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                              ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```

Ngix Server:

```nginx
server {
    server_name api.assamhut.com www.api.assamhut.com;
    root /var/www/api.assamhut.com/public;
    index index.php;
    charset utf-8;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "*";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";


    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

   location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "*" always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Requested-With' always;
    # required to be able to read Authorization header in frontend
    #add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Authorization' always;

        }
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
     }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.assamhut.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.assamhut.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = api.assamhut.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name api.assamhut.com www.api.assamhut.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is **not** a request header

Comment: why not use https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Comment: @flakerimi Because the package is already included in Laravel! It just needs to adjust some configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.1 API Enable Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors)

Answer (score 3):

**Handle cors error**

1. create a middleware with name "Cors" : ***php artisan make:middleware Cors***
2. open the Kernel add the cors created "\App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class" as the last item inside the **$middleware** and not inside **$middlewareGroups**
3. inside cors middleware add the following code:

   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {

   ```
   return $next($request)
       ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
       ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*')
       ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
   ```

   }

Comment: after adding Middleware I am able to call API In Laravel Thank you soo much.

Comment: @AazadRkhan you are must welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

The `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is set inside response headers, not requests. In your Laravel application (the one you try to send your request to), check the CORS settings under the `config\cors.php` file.

For **Laravel 7 and later**, it should be something like this to allow all origins/methods:

```php
    'paths' => ['*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
```

For laravel earlier than 7, you can use this package:
https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors (FYI, this package is used in laravel 7 and 8 out of box)

You can check the response headers by simply sending a normal request to the server using Postman or any other browser and you should see something like `access-control-allow-origin: *` in the response header.

If the Laravel config and the response header differ, make sure that if the application is behind a reverse proxy, cloud firewalls or services like that, they do not override response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Also allow headers.

Ex:

```
return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "*");
```