# Getting CORS error while calling API from Angular 16 to Laravel 10

Tags: javascript, php, angular, laravel

Getting below error while calling API from Angular to Laravel

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/authenticate' from origin 'http://localhost:4201' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I already tried adding headers in Angular for CORS but nothing worked for me.
I have checked Laravel 10 cors file every thing is good from there and I also added below code in boostrap/app.php

```php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, userKey, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, observe, enctype, Content-Length, X-Csrf-Token");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: I think you might need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in your list of headers in php file

Comment: Have you added the X-CSRF-TOKEN to your headers coming *from* Angular? Every POST submission should have some sort of CSRF token added to it

Comment: Can you post your `config/cors.php` file?

Comment: @patricus it is same as laravel default cors.php file, I haven't  changed anything
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/config/cors.php

Comment: @aynber I am doing get request from Angular

Comment: @Yogi I tried searching and finding solutions online for 2-3 hours but nothing works for me

Comment: @aynber how to set X-CSRF-TOKEN from Angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below Suggestion, Add Middle as instructed in Stack Overflow Answer.

[CORS error, unable to solve, Why always getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68386224/cors-error-unable-to-solve-why-always-getting-access-control-allow-origin/69879818#69879818)

Comment: Now it's working

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a popular package called `fruitcake/laravel-cors` that you can use to handle CORS.

```
composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors
```

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cors"
```

config/cors.php:

```
'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:4201'], // or maybe ['*']
```

Ensure the Cors middleware is included in your global middleware or in your API middleware group in app/Http/Kernel.php:

```
\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
```

Don't forget to run:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Just FYI, `fruitcate/laravel-cors` has been included in the Laravel skeleton since 7.0.0. Additionally, it was promoted from the Laravel skeleton to the Laravel framework in 9.2.0, and they moved to a new internal middleware: `Illuminate\Http\Middleware\HandleCors`. OP specified Laravel 10, so this is already all installed.

Comment: Yes as @patricus says it is already installed in laravel 10