# CORS policy problem with Angular 10 and Laravel 6 project

Tags: angular, laravel

working with Angular 10 and Laravel 6 api project and now occurred following error message in my console here,

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`
``
how could I fix this problem here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.1 API Enable Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors)

Comment: there is at least 10 other question about cors and laravel. search before posting your question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in bootstrap/app.php:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');
```