# Laravel and Nuxtjs cors problem showing upload file

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I host my code on digitalocean

Frontend use **Nuxt js** and Backend use **Laravel**

**I test api using postman backend api ok**

Error: **strict-origin-when-cross-origin**

```
modules: [
 // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
 '@nuxtjs/axios',
 '@nuxtjs/sitemap',
 '@nuxtjs/proxy',
],

axios: {
 proxy: true,
 prefix: 'http://api.mydomain.com/api'
},

proxy: {
 '/api/': 'http://api.mydomain.com/api',
},
```

Comment: you need to enable cors on your backend. what is your laravel version?

Comment: already enable, i test using postman the result ok, but online say error

Comment: Postman works because it bypasses CORS. Hence it's not blocked in Postman mainly because it's not client side but more of a server. You need to set CORS on Laravel. Voted for a close.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.1 API Enable Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors)