# How to fix /sanctum/csrf-cookie errors

Tags: reactjs, laravel, runtime-error, laravel-sanctum, csrf-token

I am creating react js project with the `Laravel` Sanctum Axios API. When I get the sign-up page it shows the below error.

cors.php

```
<?php
```

return [

```
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie','register', 'login' ],

'allowed_methods' => [ 
    'GET', 
    'POST', 
    'PUT', 
    'PATCH', 
    'DELETE', 
    'OPTIONS'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => [  
    'Origin',
    'Content-Type', 
    'Accept',
    'Authorization',
    'X-Requested-With',
    'X-CSRF-Token',
    
    ],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

];

Now below error shown
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-xsrf-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

config/Session.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return [

    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),

  

    'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 120),

    'expire_on_close' => false,  
    'encrypt' => false,

    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),

  
    'connection' => env('SESSION_CONNECTION', null),

    
    'table' => 'sessions',

 
    'store' => env('SESSION_STORE', null),

   
    'lottery' => [2, 100],

    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),

 

    'path' => '/',

    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),

    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE'),

    'http_only' => true,

    'same_site' => 'lax',

];
```

.env file

```
APP_NAME="Crafty Shop"
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:ECzTCbd8nfS6I82jRsd4sj4Bo6yJa0GRTfyTOrOoCno=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3310
DB_DATABASE=crafty
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

app.js

```
axios.defaults.baseURL= "http://localhost:8000/";
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] ='application/json';
axios.defaults.headers.post['Accept'] ='application/json';
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    config.headers.Authorization = token ? 'Bearer ${}':'';
    return config;
});
```

Login.js

```
axios.get('/sanctum/csrf-cookie').then(response => {
    axios.post('api/login',data).then(res =>{
        if(res.data.status === 200){
            localStorage.setItem('auth_token', res.data.token);
            localStorage.setItem('auth_name', res.data.username);
            swal("Success", res.data.message,"success");
            console.log(res.data.username);
            history.push('/');
      
        }
        else if(res.data.status === 401){
            swal("Warning", res.data.message,"warning");
        }
        else{
            setLogin({...loginInput,error_list:res.data.validation_errors});
        }
    });
});
```

Sanctum.php

```
<?php

return [

    'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
   


    'guard' => ['web'],

   
    'middleware' => [
        'verify_csrf_token' => App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        'encrypt_cookies' => App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
          'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class,
    ],

];
```

Comment: can you put error in question instead image

Comment: Go to the network tab in the browser and look at the preflight request to see what it returns. Then go to the log files and check for what error the request threw.

Comment: Please can you add the code from your `config/cors.php` file.

Comment: Ok.Thank you.I edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give access to your front localhost to send requests to the back-end API.

So I recommend you carefully follow the instructions from the laravel website:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-configuration

and if you would have any questions about some steps you can ask me.

But I think your problem is that your front URL cannot send requests and you have to allow it. but anyway first you have to follow the steps from the link

Comment: show us your .env file, show how are you calling sanctum from the Axios, and show us config/session.php as well

Comment: Can you also add config/sanctum.php

Comment: try to add 


`SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS = localhost,localhost:8080,127.0.0.1:8080,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1
SESSION_DOMAIN = localhost`
 that in your .env file

Comment: and if it did not work add that in your config/sanctum.php: 
`'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
        env('APP_URL') ? ','.parse_url(env('APP_URL'), PHP_URL_HOST) : ''
    ))),
`

Comment: I added Sanctum.php file

Comment: did you try to add it in your .env file? do you still have same error?

Comment: I will  add  my codes in github and can you check fix this error?

Comment: Yes ..still have same error. Csrf-cookie 204  status in network @VasoGamdelidze

Comment: For, the testing reasons, in cors.php can you allow all headers `'allowed_headers' => ['*']`, and all methods? `'allowed_methods' => ['*']`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239805/discussion-between-vaso-gamdelidze-and-nirodha-lakmali).

Answer (score 0):

You `MUST` enable `CORS` on your server app.
Find out how `Laravel` does this.

This question may help you.
[Laravel CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors)