# axios giving [AxiosError: Network Error] in react native

Tags: react-native, axios

i am new to react native and i am trying to submit a api using axios in react native but i am getiign [AxiosError: Network Error] i dont know what this is or how i can fix this

```
 function getdata() {
 
    const Data = {
      babyname: babyname,
      password: name,
      email: email,
      phone: nuber,

      period: mydate,
    };

    console.log(Data);
  
    axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/details/',
      data: Data,
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

i used the default inspect elemt in react native and have network tab opened
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is your API created using NodeJS?

Comment: i created aPi in laravel php

Comment: Have you checked the CORS polices of your server ?

Comment: Try to enable CORS in your API. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.1 API Enable Cors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33076705/laravel-5-1-api-enable-cors)

Comment: check Is the api working fine in postman, and if you are using emulator, check the internet working in your emulator or not?

Comment: in postman api is woeking and i ahave interrnet woeking @VickyAhuja

Comment: @jisaks check my answer, it may help you with your query

Comment: @Bishan my apis are working in post man

Comment: @Dilshan apis are woeking in postman

Comment: Yes because Postman does not enforce CORS & ignore them. Try the answers on the question added by @Bishan

Comment: @Dilshan i am sure what changes i must be making can u write a  answer with step by step so i can try

Comment: There's no need to duplicate answers here. Try the 1st and 2nd answers on that questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is from Ip that you are trying to get connected

it seems that you are using an android emulator, so 127.0.0.1 is not the IP that runs in Postman

if 127.0.0.1 is your localhost, changing that to 10.0.2.2 might fix your problem

```
axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/details/',
  data: Data,
})
```

Comment: ok this is working how did u come up with this ip

Comment: this is Ip that emulator connect to your localhost (127.0.0.1)

Comment: oke so i sould use this ip when ever i use emulator?

Comment: if you are running your laravel server in your device yes, but if you upload that to any host ,  domain or ip of that host must be  set here

Answer (score 0):

In my case a both, changing to `http://10.0.2.2` and adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in the `AndroidMainfest.XML` also didn’t work.

Instead, I resolved it this way: In `android/app/src/debug`, I created an `xml/react_native_config.xml` file, and then copied the code below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="false">{yourDomain}</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```