# How to make a POST request in react native

Tags: react-native, axios

I am trying to do an axios post in react native.
In postman, it is working but in app, it is not working. Can someone help?

```
var Data = {
        name: name,
        email: email,
      };
    }
   axios
      .post('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/register', Data)

      .then(res => {
        alert(res);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(JSON.stringify(err)));
  }
```

[image]

this is the error

> {"message":"Network Error","name":"AxiosError","stack":"AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.sukprsavam&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true:103294:16)","config":{"transitional":{"silentJSONParsing":true,"forcedJSONParsing":true,"clarifyTimeoutError":false},"adapter":["xhr","http"],"transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"timeout":0,"xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN","xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN","maxContentLength":-1,"maxBodyLength":-1,"env":{},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json"},"method":"post","url":"http://103.161.55.43/api/register/","data":"{"name":"dadkn","email":"sdfgsf@gmail.com","baby_date":"27/12/2022"}"},"code":"ERR_NETWORK","status":null}

Comment: you need to pass your ip address in url then check

Comment: @MahammadMomin can u share how my uri will look like so i can try

Comment: I think he meant to say that ip addresses you are using in postman and the app are not the same.

Comment: react native requires this ip beacuse it is a emulator @NirajNiroula

Comment: @NirajNiroula https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74750780/axios-giving-axioserror-network-error-in-react-native have a look at this

Comment: http://<yourip>/

Comment: its not helping same error

Comment: @jisaks Ok. Did [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74767340/4387975) help you then? Also, please check if the internet is available in your emulator or not.

Comment: @NirajNiroula i added larvel passport in to my backend for generating token this answer was working befor that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IOS and Android don't work with HTTP protocol by default. It's not secure. If you can migrate to HTTPS, all will work fine.

But you can disable this secure option by updating the following files;

**Android (AndroidManifest.xml)**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
       //-------add this attribute-------//
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> 
    
    </application>
```

**IOS (Info.plist)**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```